# How to store 1:1 relationship in microservice architechture?

Tags: mysql, relationship

I'm developing an app with a microserivce / domain driven design architecture with an SQL database.

I have two tables: **product** and **seo**. **Product** stores information about a product price, name, etc. And **seo** stores page title, description, for the product.

The relationship between products and seos is a 1:1 relationship.

---

What is the best way to create this relationship in a microservice/DDD architecture?

I can think of three options:

1. Product table stores `seo_id`, and seo table stores `product_id` - (they store eachothers id's)

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  seo_id UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE seo (
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  product_id UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

2. Product table stores `seo_id`, but seo does not store the `product_id` - (only product store's its seo_id)

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  seo_id UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE seo (
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

3. Seo table stores `product_id`, but product does not store the `seo_id` - (only seo store's its product_id)

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE seo (
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  product_id UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Should each table store the other's ID? Or should only one store the other's ID?

Comment: Microservice has absolutely nothing to do with this

Comment: I would go for Option 3, Seo table has Product_id in it

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I just added it.. I think that also makes sense. But I wonder if there is a rule of thumb to help make this decision easier in the future.

Comment: in 1:1 relationships you don't need two tables, as none oft the rows are reused. so you model is flawed

Comment: @nbk should seo be merged into the product then? Perhaps I can make it more useful by allowing SEO to be used with other tables too.. such as a collection? And in this case seo would not store any ID's I guess, and the product would store the seo id, and collection would store seo id perhaps

Comment: options 2 and 3 are 1-to-many designs, only option 1 is 1:1. You can make options 2 and 3 1:1 by adding unique index to the FK field and make them non-null. Which one is more suitable for you we cannot tell. But with such small tables I would probably combine them together in a single table as @nbk suggested.

Comment: @Acidic9 a 1:1 table is only need to expand one table if it is to enlarge one table sp decide which table is the master